# Making a vertical array using Angular/Lodash

Tags: arrays, angular, range, lodash, chunks

I was wondering how can you make the order of an array from this (I want multiple columns and two rows only):

[Original order of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7yQF.png)

To this? Like, how do I reorder this so the numbers will be alternating (maybe separating into odd or even groups will work? No?)

[Intended order of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3cbA.png)

For the numbers, I use a range function.

```
a: object[] = _.chunk(_.range(1, 9), 4);
b: object[] = _.chunk(_.range(9, 17), 4);
```

How can I divide the range of array so that only the odd ones will appear on top, even ones on the bottom? Hope anyone can help, thanks a lot.

Update: I tried using **_.partition** but only hard coded numbers. How if I need to use a range **(_.range)**?

`_.partition([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], n => n % 2);`

Comment: What programming language do you use? Remember, the **tags** attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question

Comment: @fcdt I am using Angular for this, sorry, I am just a new user so I forgot to put in the language/framework I use! Thanks for the tip, BTW :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let groups = _.groupBy(arr,num=>num%2===0?'even':'odd')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num) { return num % 2 == 0; });
// => [2, 4, 6]
```